# How to find id in silverlight data grid

Tags: silverlight

I need get the id of an images which is place inside a datatemplate.. the code is given below.

```
<sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
 <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="colDeleteContent" IsReadOnly="True" Header="Delete Content" Width="100" CanUserResize="False">
   <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel x:Name="spDeleteContent" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="20" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Vertical">
             <Image x:Name="imgDeleteContent" Source="Assets/Images/close.png" Height="15" Tag="Assets/Images/close.png" Width="15" Margin="0" Cursor="Hand" Opacity="0" />
         </StackPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
     </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
</sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
```

I need to get the id of the "imgDeleteContent" which i have placed inside that datatemplate stackpanel in my code behind.

Pls help, Thanks

Comment: Do you know the index of the row, the image of which you want to find?

Comment: @vorrtex i don't know the index of the row, i didn't get your point.. that image is placed in zeroth (0th) column in the data grid. thanks for your reply.

Comment: First, you should retrieve the row by index, here is the example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4065667/427225. Then you should retrieve the cell value, like here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3121715/427225. After that you can try to cast the element to StackPanel and find the image. But it would be much easier and better to use view models and data binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could find control name on grid loading row event like below

```
StackPanel Sp = grdProducts.Columns[1].GetCellContent(e.Row) as StackPanel;
```

then use quick watch to find that imgDeleteContent control. and do whatever yo like :)